# How could I add a PHP variable inside a query?

Tags: php, html, sql, variables, inner-join

Here I create a query with inner join to include all my tables; but I want to store directly inside the query `$id_foro` where `id_foro` is part of `equipo01_foros`?
so, could I create somethign like `equipo01 foros.id_foro = $id_foro`?

I want the `$id_foro` to  display all the different data from the tables I select

```
$q = "
select 
    equipo01_foros.id_foro, 
    equipo01_usuarios.usuario,
    equipo01_foros.nombreforo, 
    equipo01_foros.descripcion,
    equipo01_comentarios.id_comentarios, 
    equipo01_comentarios.comentarios
from equipo01_usuarios
inner join equipo01_comentarios 
  on equipo01_usuarios.id_usuarios = equipo01_comentarios.id_usuarios 
inner join equipo01_foros
  on equipo01_foros.id_foro = equipo01_comentarios.id_foro
 inner join equipo01_foros 
 on equipo01_foros.id_foro
";
```

Comment: any php variable inside double quotes is expanded to its value

Comment: You should use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) if you want to use any variable from your PHP-code in your query.

Answer (score 0):

"equipo01 foros.id_foro = '{$id_foro}'"

Within the double quoted strings, variables in curly brackets are replaced with the value.  They expand in quotes without the curly brackets, but sometimes need to be bracketed to avoid ambiguous interpretation.  So I just do it all the time.  I use the single quotes even with numeric keys, so that queries where the variable is empty or a string fail to get a result rather than generate a SQL parse error.  Obviously, if the variable comes from client input, it needs to be validated in some way before you use it in a SQL statement.